# How to ⌘+lft click on Laravel's view name in PhpStorm to open it?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpstorm

The same behavior works great with PHP classes, models, interfaces etc. Let's assume you have installed [**Laravel** 5 IDE Helper Generator](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper). Then once you hover on `PersonRepository` and **⌘ + click** it:

```
public function create(PersonRepository $personRepository)
{
    (...)
```

**PhpStorm** will open `PersonRepository` interface so you can deal with the file extra fast. Fine.

Now imagine view reference like the one below:

```
return view('foo.bar', compact('lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor'));
```

I would like to hover `bar` so I can **⌘ + click** it and then:

```
/resouces/views/foo/bar.blade.php
```

will be opened. Any easy way to achieve that or am I missing something? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try the PhpStorm plugin for Laravel?

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7532

Comment: Thanks Barry! 

Comment: It appears that currently the Compatibility Range for this plugin is 2017.3 — 2022.1.4. Is this plugin still maintained?

Comment: This is a really good plugin, but unfortunately, the GitHub repo is archived and the author isn't supporting it anymore. It's been years since an update was released.